# Nook emulator on eclipse won't load (looping?)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I can't get the Nook emulator to actually start, it just gets caught in some kind of loop. Below is the logcat (this same pattern repeats over and over). Any thoughts?

```
12-14 03:09:08.784: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 20K, 76% free 508K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-14 03:09:08.824: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 74% free 535K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-14 03:09:08.854: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15K, 72% free 575K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-14 03:09:08.914: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 71% free 601K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-14 03:09:08.984: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 30K, 69% free 635K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-14 03:09:09.014: D/TextLayoutCache(20852): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
12-14 03:09:09.034: W/Zygote(20852): Class not found for preloading: android.media.AudioManager$2
12-14 03:09:09.094: I/dalvikvm(20852): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
12-14 03:09:09.094: D/MtpDeviceJNI(20852): register_android_mtp_MtpDevice
12-14 03:09:09.104: I/dalvikvm(20852): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
12-14 03:09:09.104: I/dalvikvm(20852): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
12-14 03:09:09.104: W/MediaProfiles(20852): could not find media config xml file
12-14 03:09:09.104: W/Zygote(20852): Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher
12-14 03:09:09.114: W/Zygote(20852): Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher$Stub
12-14 03:09:09.134: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 19K, 68% free 675K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-14 03:09:09.384: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 218K, 53% free 968K/2048K, paused 15ms
12-14 03:09:09.444: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 43K, 50% free 1025K/2048K, paused 2ms+1ms
12-14 03:09:09.514: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 49% free 1054K/2048K, paused 2ms+1ms
12-14 03:09:09.584: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 47% free 1102K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-14 03:09:09.634: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 23K, 43% free 1169K/2048K, paused 1ms+2ms
12-14 03:09:09.754: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 48K, 30% free 1448K/2048K, paused 2ms+2ms
12-14 03:09:09.764: W/Zygote(20852): Class not found for preloading: android.text.TextDirectionHeuristics$CharCount
12-14 03:09:09.784: W/Zygote(20852): Class not found for preloading: android.text.method.WordIterator$1
12-14 03:09:09.844: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 35K, 28% free 1482K/2048K, paused 2ms+2ms
12-14 03:09:09.904: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 27% free 1504K/2048K, paused 2ms+2ms
12-14 03:09:10.034: I/dalvikvm(20852): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libwebcore.so)
12-14 03:09:10.034: D/dalvikvm(20852): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libchromium_net.so 0x0, skipping init
12-14 03:09:10.114: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 25% free 1553K/2048K, paused 3ms+2ms
12-14 03:09:10.184: W/Zygote(20852): Class not found for preloading: android.widget.EdgeGlow
12-14 03:09:10.284: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 25K, 23% free 1582K/2048K, paused 2ms+2ms
12-14 03:09:10.464: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 71K, 21% free 1627K/2048K, paused 3ms+2ms
12-14 03:09:10.484: E/PhonePolicy(20852): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
12-14 03:09:10.544: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 20% free 1649K/2048K, paused 3ms+2ms
12-14 03:09:10.624: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 19% free 1678K/2048K, paused 2ms+2ms
12-14 03:09:10.674: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 17% free 1708K/2048K, paused 3ms+2ms
12-14 03:09:10.734: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 16% free 1734K/2048K, paused 2ms+2ms
12-14 03:09:10.794: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 31K, 14% free 1762K/2048K, paused 2ms+2ms
12-14 03:09:10.864: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 71K, 12% free 1817K/2048K, paused 3ms+2ms
12-14 03:09:10.934: D/dalvikvm(20852): GC_EXPLICIT freed 39K, 11% free 1833K/2048K, paused 2ms+3ms
12-14 03:09:12.474: I/SurfaceFlinger(20856): SurfaceFlinger is starting
12-14 03:09:12.484: I/SurfaceFlinger(20856): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
12-14 03:09:12.494: D/gralloc_goldfish(20856): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-14 03:09:12.494: E/FramebufferNativeWindow(20856): couldn't open framebuffer HAL (No such file or directory)
12-14 03:09:12.494: E/SurfaceFlinger(20856): Display subsystem failed to initialize. check logs. exiting...
12-14 03:09:12.704: D/AndroidRuntime(20859): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
12-14 03:09:12.704: D/AndroidRuntime(20859): CheckJNI is ON
12-14 03:09:13.134: I/SamplingProfilerIntegration(20859): Profiling disabled.
12-14 03:09:13.154: I/Zygote(20859): Preloading classes...
12-14 03:09:13.164: D/dalvikvm(20859): GC_EXPLICIT freed 36K, 81% free 408K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-14 03:09:13.204: D/dalvikvm(20859): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 77% free 472K/2048K, paused 0ms+0ms
```